# Why is UserManager.Find() returning null if my UserName is email based?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to implement email address based usernames in AspNet.Identity for MVC5, but I'm having trouble with the UserManager finding my user.

```
public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; private set; }

public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
{
    UserManager = userManager;
    UserManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(UserManager)
    {
        AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false
    };
}
```

In my login post method:

```
var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
```

user is null.

Am I using the wrong method to find my user by username and password?

Even if I use

```
var db = new ApplicationDBContext();
var user = db.Users.Find(model.UserName);
```

or

```
var db = new ApplicationDBContext();
var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == model.UserName);
```

I get a null

**UPDATE**

It looks like I'm getting null, because the users I'm trying to seed aren't being seeded.  Anyone know why?

This is my seed for the users in the Configuration.cs (migrations):

```
var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
var users = new List<ApplicationUser>()
{
    new ApplicationUser { UserName = "batman@email.com", IsActive = true },
    new ApplicationUser { UserName = "superman@email.com", IsActive = true },
    new ApplicationUser { UserName = "wonderwoman@email.com", IsActive = false }
};
users.ForEach(i => manager.Create(i, "password"));
```

If I seed the users with non-email UserNames, the seed goes through with no problem:

```
new ApplicationUser { UserName = "batman", IsActive = true },
new ApplicationUser { UserName = "superman", IsActive = true },
new ApplicationUser { UserName = "wonderwoman", IsActive = false }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.  I needed to change the validator in my seed:

```
var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
{
    AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false
};
var users = new List<ApplicationUser>()
{
    new ApplicationUser { UserName = "batman@email.com", IsActive = true },
    new ApplicationUser { UserName = "superman@email.com", IsActive = true },
    new ApplicationUser { UserName = "wonderwoman@email.com", IsActive = false }
};
users.ForEach(i => manager.Create(i, "December 2013"));
```

After this, I was able to seed my email-based UserNames.

I left this in my AccountController for adding users:

```
public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
{
    UserManager = userManager;
    UserManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(UserManager)
    {
        AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was tearing my hair out till I found this.

Answer (score 0):

Verify you have added Database Init Strategy Or doing manual updates.

e.g. [Database Init Strategy]

```
Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ApplicationDbContext, Configuration>());
```

Comment: When I do `update-database` everything else in my seed populates, except the users.